# Datatable taking too long to display

Tags: php, datatable

I am trying to display a datatable but it's taking too long around 10-12 seconds (for almost 1900 rows).
When I test my request in PHPMyAdmin it takes 0.0122 secs.
I don't understand why it's taking so much time to display the datatable.

If someone could help me it will be nice (sorry for my bad english).
Here is my code:

```
<?php ``
           include 'database.php';
           $pdo = Database::connect();
           $sql = 'SELECT * FROM sav2013_et_2014';
           foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                   echo '<tr>';
                   echo '<td>'. $row['Num_sav'] . '</td>';
                   echo '<td>'. $row['Num_commande'] . '</td>';
                   echo '<td>'. $row['Nom_produit'] . '</td>';
                   echo '<td>'. $row['Nom'] . '</td>';
                   echo '<td>'. $row['Prenom'] . '</td>';
                   echo '<td>'. $row['Statut'] . '</td>';
                   echo '<td>';
                   echo '<a class="btn btn-info btn-large active" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Editer</a>';
                   echo '&nbsp;';
                   echo '</td>';
                   echo '</tr>';
               }
       Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it (not to fimiliar with pdo) But the way you have it now might be that you keep doing the same query over and over again. So if that is actually what happens put it in a result var first.

```
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM sav2013_et_2014';
   $result = $pdo->query($sql);
   foreach ($result as $row) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I tried the code above but its taking the same time 10-12 secs to display it.

Comment: Okay how long does it take if you just var_dump($result); and comment out the foreach loop?

Comment: So I added the line "var_dump($result);" and commented the foreach loop. Now I can't see any data in the table (it's normal) but a message appear : " object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(29) "SELECT * FROM sav2013_et_2014" }  " this display takes 0.1 secs to appear.

Comment: Okay so it isn't the query that is slow, it has to be something in the loop that is making this slow. How long does it take if you comment this line out? //echo '<a class="btn btn-info btn-large active" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Editer</a>';

Comment: I commented this line :"   echo '<a class="btn btn-info btn-large active" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Editer</a>';  " but it still take 10-12 secs to display the table.

Comment: I think that I found the problem. I forgot to say you that I am using the plugin "datatable" ==>"  http://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html ". I have to put a javascript code to add some option in my datatable. I tried to remove those options and then the datatable load instantly. I don't know how to resolve this problem because I need this script for my project.

Comment: I think theres alot of other datatables api's out there that might suit your amount of data better maybe this is built for small sets

Comment: I didn't find a better Api than Datatable. I am working at this project for 1 month. Anyway really thank you Herriekrekel for your help :)

Comment: You should take a look at server side proccesing with your current api http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Ok I will see if I can do something with the server side. Thanks again